# Example code from typing library causes TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable, why?

Tags: python, typing

Considering to Python Docs for `typing` why code below isn't working?

```
>>> Vector = list[float]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

In docs there is the same example as I mentioned above. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases)

```
Vector = list[float]

def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
    return [scalar * num for num in vector]
```

I didn't find question about this example.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: must be lower than 3.9

Comment: This functionality is new in Python 3.9. If you use the checkbox at the top of the documentation, you can see how it works for older versions. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ability to use the `[]` operator on types like `list` for type hinting was added in 3.9.

[What's new in Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections)

In earlier versions it will generate the error you describe, and you need to import the `List` object from `typing` instead.

```
from typing import List
List[float]
```

Comment: right, I didn't find that I was reading docs for 3.9, thanks!